# How to express willingness to travel in an interview? Should I mention private business travel?

Tags: interviewing, hiring-process, travel

I am currently applying for a new job. The jobs I am applying for are based on the willingness to travel. In my current job I am not required to travel much (once a year).

I already had an interview and they asked me about my willingness to travel. I got really excited, because I love getting to know people from different cultures, working with them and also travelling in general.
Because I was so excited about travelling the recruiter just told me that this is not for vacation! Of course this is clear to me! But after that they did not even listen to the rest of proof I gave.

The next interview will be soon. (And this is a job I am even more eager to get than the other one). They asked me about travel willingness beforehand so I carefully replied that I have studied abroad and been one a few business Trips (from my current job).

My personal situation is that my father is self-employed and therefore took me and my brothers and sisters on business trips abroad from when we were young. I really liked these travels even though I am not sure if I can compare it to general business travel.

During my studies I have been tutoring international students at my university. Some of them I visited in there home country. Even though this was private travel only, of course I got to know the culture and I oriented myself through the places.

So do you think one should mention trips like that? Or what is the recruiters intention and focus about travel willingness?

Answer (score 5):

Sounding too excited may come across as being too much about your desires and not about the companies needs.

I would say something like "I am well aware that this position could(would) involve travel and that is not a problem for me at all".

If they ask about your travel experience after that, you could go into more detail to show that you can easily handle the travelling requirements.

Comment: The only thing I would add is that if it's appropriate to show more detail, do so only after reading the room - use your varied experiences and interests to your advantage. Generally, the Hiring Team doesn't want or need your life story. --- sidenote: that is what worked for me in past interviews for a position the required boatloads of travel.

Comment: I think it would be okay to say, "I traveled a lot when I was younger with my father for his business trips and really enjoyed it. I wouldn't mind any business travel at all." Short and simple and shows a little bit of personal motivation. But that's just my opinion. I like to hear about people and their motivations.

Answer (score 2):

> My personal situation is that my father is self-employed and therefore
>   took me and my brothers and sisters on business trips abroad from when
>   we were young.
>
> So do you think one should mention trips like that?

It would make complete sense to indicate that you have seen up close what travel for business is like, and to relate how your father took you along.

Emphasize the business trip aspects, and learning to tolerate the tedium and being away from home that your father experienced.

De-emphasize the "fun", "learning other cultures", and related aspects. These are far less likely when you are the one doing the business travel - there usually isn't that much time for much fun.